# MongoDB Scope of Indexes when Searching and Filtering

Tags: mongodb, indexing

We have a huge collection where we query for specific documents each minute.

the query looks like:

```
db.mycoll.find({
   date: {$lt: now}, 
   public: true, 
   mail.delivered: false
}).sort({
   remote.continent: 1,
   remote.country: 1,
   remote.city: 1
})
```

(the data is example data, the real schema looks a bit different)

how would I need to define an index that this query gets faster?

do multiple indexes work together? e.g. when I define one index for the sorting, one for public and one for the rest?

how expensive is indexing?

Comment: Yes you can have compound indexes https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-compound/. If this is the only type of query on the collection, you can have one compound. You can also have index on either and mongodb will take intersection index (max 2)

Comment: no, there are many queries on the collection. This query is executed once a minute, there are queries that search for slightly different data once every 30 minutes and so on. also the logic to update the datasets would porbably need other indexes; but as the profiling tells me with 51seconds this is by far the slowest query.

Comment: generally, an index on `date` intersecting with an index with `{public: 1, 'mail.delivered': 1}` would do your job. The `date` index would be more or less used in most of your queries.